# Nginx rule to redirect user to a /404 url if the current url ends with index.php

Tags: nginx, redirect, http-status-code-404

I am looking for an NGINX rule for my website.
If the user lands on my website with a URL having index.php at the end I want to redirect them to a /404 URL with a 404 status code.

for eg 
http://example.com/index.php => http://example.com/404 
http://example.com/abcd/index.php => http://example.com/404 
http://example.com/abcd/dcba/index.php => http://example.com/404

so far I have this but this doesn't work.

```
location ~ index\.php$ {
        return 404 https://$host/404;
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to ServerFault. Regex locations are proceed in order they appeared in the config, do you have any other regex location blocks before this one?

Comment: no, I don't at the moment.

Comment: And what you are getting now with this config?

Comment: so when i visit a page with index.php in it it fails to load anything "This site can’t be reached" with failed status

Comment: Try: `return 404; error_page 404 /404;`

Comment: @RichardSmith your solution kind of worked for me thanks.